# ColdFusion - Vonage Inboud voice api call Answer Webhook CURL - issue with ncco object can't send multiple response to text to speech

Tags: curl, coldfusion, voice, coldfusion-8, vonage

I am successfully able to recive inboud call on my webhook and it works nicely i got the automated voice of below text it is working good. however i am getting "**Unexpected content type: text/html; charset=UTF-8**" on events.

```html
<cfset ncco = '
{
        "action": "talk",
        "text": "Press 1, for maybe, and 2, for not sure, followed by the hash key.",
        "language": "en-US",
        "style": 6,
        "bargeIn": true
}'>
<cfhttp method="PUT" url="https://api.nexmo.com/v1/calls/#responsetxt.uuid#/talk" result="httpResponse">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer #jwtToken#" />        
        <cfhttpparam type="body" value='#ncco#' />
</cfhttp>
```

when I got inboud and pass the following ncco it doesnt work and call disconnected. but this works good with outbound call voice recorded and transcripted.

```html
<cfset ncco = [
        {
            "action": "record",
            "eventUrl": ["https://example.com/virrtualcall/input.cfm"],
            "transcription":
            {
                    "eventMethod": "POST",
                    "eventUrl":["https://example.com.com/virrtualcall/input.cfm"],
                    "language": "en-US",
                    "sentimentAnalysis": "true"
            }
        },          
        {
                "action": "talk",
                "text": "Please let us know what is your problem",
                "language": "en-US",
                "style": 6,
                "premium": true,
                "bargeIn": true
        },
        {
                "action": "input",
                "type": [
                        "dtmf"
                ],
                "dtmf": {
                        "submitOnHash": true,
                        "timeOut": 10
                }
        },
        {
                "action": "talk",
                "text": "Thanks for your response, goodbye.",
                "language": "en-US",
                "style": 2
        }
]>
```

this is the oubound call works nice with above ncco **i want this ncco something like should work with inbound call.** Can someone help me out with this.

```html
<cfhttp method="POST" url="https://api.nexmo.com/v1/calls" result="httpResponse">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer #jwtToken#" />        
        <cfhttpparam type="body" value='{"to":[{"type":"phone","number":"#toNumber#"}],"from":{"type":"phone","number":"#fromNumber#"},"ncco":#serializeJSON(ncco)#}' />
</cfhttp>
```

Thanks

Comment: You are creating json stings manually and injecting objects with serializeJSON into those variables. Try creating and work with one cfml struct only and output it once with serializeJSON(myStruct) to the body, instead.

Comment: I have already tried this option earlier.  Can you please create one for me so i can test it. may be your one works for me. Thanks in advance.